# Odd Behavour on Float Right on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am encountering a weird issue, **only in Chrome**, which adds extra space on top of an element with `float: right`, only upon resize (notice how the name then appears under the header fold):

[image]

Only when I resize back to the desktop media query do I encounter this issue.

My HTML is like this:

```
<header role="banner">
    <a class = "logo"...>...</a> <!-- inline-block -->
    <div class = "client">...</div> <!-- float: right -->
    <nav role = "navigation">...</nav> <!-- display: inline-block -->
</header>
```

See the name "Michael"? It appears to the right, properly positioned in the main navigation. But once the browser resizes, at the end, it is moved to the bottom.

Any idea what's causing this and how I can fix it?  I have verified that this occurs with the latest version of Chrome on Windows and Mac.

Comment: What do you mean by "which adds extra space on top of an element"? On top of the word "Michael" on the right there? I'm not sure what behavior you're referring to. Nice design btw.

Comment: See the name "Michael"?  It appears to the right, properly positioned in the main navigation.  But once the browser resizes, at the end, it is moved to the bottom.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now. If that's really only happening in Chrome, sure sounds like a bug.

Comment: Just replicated the same problem in a different, separate codebase.  I will file a bug report with Chrome.

Comment: Out of curiosity, @user1429980, which version of Chrome and which OS are you using?

Comment: Also, before filing a bug report, you may wish to validate your markup: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Not 100% sure, but float and inline(-block) are not best friends.

Answer (score 0):

Switch positions between "client" and "navigation" like this:

```
<header role="banner">
    <a class = "logo"...>...</a> <!-- inline-block -->
    <nav role = "navigation">...</nav> <!-- display: inline-block -->
    <div class = "client">...</div> <!-- float: right -->
</header>
```

The problem is that the navigation menu was floating around your "client" container. The elements after the floating element will flow around it when they are close.